# Finding elements that appear in groups most

Tags: algorithm, grouping, counting

Having trouble figuring out how to go about this algorithm.

**Input**: any number of lists each holding elements grouped by a common attribute

For example,

`matched_by_first_name = {"bob" => [person, person, ...], "nancy" => [person, ...], ...}`

`matched_by_zip_code = {"12345" => [person, person, ...], "56789" => [person, ...], ...}`

**Output**: List of groups of people that appear most frequently in the same groups, with separate "weightings" per input list. So, I might weight two people grouped by the same first name more than I would weight two people grouped by the same zip code.

In other words:

matches = [[person, person], [person], [person, person, person]]

Basically, if there are two persons and for every single grouping they are in the same group, then they should definitely be in the same final matched group. If there's only one group they're not in, then they should probably still be matched (depending on the weighting of that group type).

Comment: Well, shortly after posting this question I looked at related questions and found out what k-means clustering is...although I don't really know how to go about it yet. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a matter of clustering or data mining. It's simply a matter of counting. E.g. in python, the class `Counter`.